# Monitoring Servicemix with Hyperic HQ

Tags: health-monitoring, apache-servicemix, hyperic

I have been able to configure Hyperic HQ to identify servicemix 4, however, It could only see the "ServiceMix 4.x Garbage Collector" service. I would like to be able to monitor activemq Queues, Endpoints, and Camel Applications (if possible)

Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue at a client recently.  We didn't find any support for doing this with HypericHQ, so we built our own basic web app using JSP, Ajax/jQuery and JMX to interface with AMQ/Camel.  Another option is to customize the [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html) and [Camel](http://camel.apache.org/web-console.html) web consoles...

Here are some notes on using JMX to monitor/manage both [ActiveMQ](http://benoday.blogspot.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html) and [Camel](http://benoday.blogspot.com/2010/08/managing-camel-routes-with-jmx-apis.html)...

http://benoday.blogspot.com/2010/08/managing-camel-routes-with-jmx-apis.html

http://benoday.blogspot.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html

Also, I know the Camel team is looking to enhance the web console in future releases (see the [3.0 roadmap](http://camel.apache.org/camel-30-roadmap.html))

good luck...

Comment: yep, I'm just relaying my experience when facing the same challenges.  He asked how to monitor endpoints, routes and queues...Hyperic simply didn't do this.